# Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080 ]: Response status 404 Spring, RESTfull ,thymleaf

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, thymeleaf

I m experiencing a problem with Spring, Rest and Thymeleafand I'm stuck there and there is not so much details about this error that I'm experiencing.

I want when I select in the form one of the options in the select tag (index.html)  to be redirected to the something.html but with the new values(with an api call ) and I'm just getting that it can't handle the request.

I want so send the value to service and controller from a html form:

The index.html:

```
<body>
<!--/*@thymesVar id="cryptos" type="java.util.Map<Integer, jasmin.merusic.domain.Crypto>"*/-->
<!--/*@thymesVar id="crypto" type="jasmin.merusic.domain.Crypto"*/-->
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title">CryptoCurrencies from API</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive" th:if="${not #maps.isEmpty(cryptos)}">
                    <table class="table table-hover ">
                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>
                               **<form th:action="@{/values/}" >
                                <select name="fiatCurrency" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                <option  selected="selected" value="USD">USD</option>
                                <option  value="EUR">Euro</option>
                                <option  value="CNY">C. Yuan</option>
                                </select>
                               </form>**
                            </th>
                            <th>Change in 24h(%)</th>
                            <th>Rank</th>
                            <th>Symbol</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr th:remove="all">
                            <td>Joe</td>
                            <td>Buck</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>foo@example.com</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr th:remove="all">
                            <td>Joe</td>
                            <td>Buck</td>
                            <td>Male</td>
                            <td>foo@example.com</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr th:each="crypto : ${cryptos.values()}">
                            <td th:text="${crypto.name}">Joe</td>
                                <span th:each="cryp : ${crypto.quotes.values()}">
                                    <td th:text="${cryp.price}">Buck</td>
                                    <td th:text="${cryp.percent_change_24h}">Buck</td>
                                </span>
                            <td th:text="${crypto.rank}">Male</td>
                            <td th:text="${crypto.symbol}">foo@example.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The controller class is like that:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

 private  ApiService apiService;

public DataController(ApiService apiService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
}

@GetMapping({"", "/", "/index","/cryptos"})
public String index(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("cryptos",apiService.getCrypto(100));

    return "index";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/values/{fiatCurrency}")
public String choseCurrency(Model model,@PathVariable String fiatCurrency){

    model.addAttribute("cryp",apiService.getInDifferentValues(fiatCurrency));

     //returns to the something.html
    return "something";
}
}
```

And the service implementation looks like this:

```
@Service
public class ApiServiceImpl implements ApiService{

private  RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
public ApiServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
}

@Override
public Map<Integer,Crypto> getCrypto(Integer limit) {

    CryptoData cryptoData = restTemplate.getForObject("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=BTC&limit=" + limit , CryptoData.class);


    return cryptoData.getData();
}

@Override
public Map<Integer, Crypto> getInDifferentValues(String fiatCurrency) {

    CryptoData cryptoData = restTemplate.
            getForObject("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=" + fiatCurrency + "&limit=100", CryptoData.class);

    return cryptoData.getData();
}
}
```

I'm a newbie in this and i came across the following error:

```
2018-10-19 20:10:40.147  WARN 15768 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://localhost:8080/values/?fiatCurrency=EUR]: Response status 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line

```
**<form th:action="@{/values/}" >
```

to

```
**<form th:action="@{/values/} + ${fiatCurrency}" method="post" >
```

This will change the request to "post" from "get"(you have "get" now in you form) and will send info as a pathvariable(as defined in your controller method) and not as a request parameter(as it is now).

Answer (score 1):

As per your error stack-trace,

> 2018-10-19 20:10:40.147  WARN 15768 --- [ctor-http-nio-4]
>   .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request
>   [GET http://localhost:8080/values/?fiatCurrency=EUR]: Response status
>   404

you have not defined a `GET` mapping for `/values`. You have defined it only for a `POST` operation, add that and it should work.

Comment: I added it and it solved this problem and i add it like this         @GetMapping(value = {"/values","/values/","", "/", "/index","/cryptos"} )
and now i have a new problem it is not failing anywhere but is not doing anything when i select another values in the select tag.